# this.$store is undefined with vuex 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I created a vue app using vuejs 2 and vuex 3.

Here is the code:
App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <button v-on:click="increment">Test</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.commit('increment')
      console.log(this.$store.state.count)
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router.js'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import store from './store.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router: router,
  store: store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I click at the button in App.vue file. it always throw error that this.$store is undefined. Did i do something wrong?
But when i add the following code in the main.js file. Everything work smoothly.

```
Vue.prototype.$store = store;
```

But did I already registered the store in Vue constructor. Why do I need that code? Can anyone show me the best way to fix it`? Thank you.

Comment: Vue.prototype.$store isn't needed, this is what `use` does. The only mistake is that you did `Vue.use(Vuex)` twice. I don't see how it can affect it this way. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It's not reproducible with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I install wrong version of vuex (v4 instead of v3). Problem solved.